# Background doesn't work, it goes up and get cut in half

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I'm creating a website login windown, and the background is an image, but the image always get cut in half and go up.

this is the code I'm using:

```
.loginbody {
    background: url(img/LoginBackground3.jfif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: sans-ser``if;   
}
```

[this is what it lookslike](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmboW.png)

[image: this is the HTML part]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing your HTML as well, but your containing element probably isn't the full height of the viewport.

If you want to make a fullscreen background image that always fills the viewport, apply your CSS to the `html` element of your page:

```
html { 
  background: url(img/LoginBackground3.jfif) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Alternatively you could set the viewport height on your `loginbody` element to `100vh`, making it the full height of the viewport:

```
.loginbody {
    background: url(img/LoginBackground3.jfif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    height:100vh;   
}
```

Comment: it's strange, bc every tutorial I watch, shares almost the same line of code for background and just works for them. Altering the height worked! thx